# JVST UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, unsatisfiedlinkerror, vst

I am trying to run an example from the JVST library, and I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   jvst-0.0.1 in java.library.path or on the classpath

I made sure that jvst-0.0.1.dll is in the same directory as the class that loads the file (compiled class, not source code), and in fact I tried even copying it in any directory of the project, but still it won't find it. Anybody has an idea why?
Thanks, Simone

EDIT: Solved, it turns out that JVST loads a 32 bits dll, and that won't work if your jdk is 64 bits. The tricky part was that the error message was changed, and it appeared as if the dll was not found.

Comment: Have you tried putting the DLL on the classpath using `-cp` or the like?

Comment: Yes, the DLL was in the classpath. As I wrote in my edit note, the problem was that the dll was 32 bits while I was running a 64 bits jdk.